# runInthisContext is confusing in node.js

Tags: node.js

Assume the following:

```js
A) vm.runInThisContext("a=5;")
B) vm.runInThisContext("var a=5;")

// Either you run A or B, `a` will be created in global object.
```

Now, assume:

```js
A) vm.runInThisContext('function test(){ a = 5;} test()')
B) vm.runInThisContext('function test(){ var a = 5;} test()')

// In both A and B, `test` is called.  Though, in A) case, `a` is  
// added to global object whereas in B, `a` is not added to global
// object.
```

I'm wondering what's really going on such that in B case, `a` is not added to global object.

Comment: This is just javascript. This is how the `var` keyword is defined to behave. Nothing special or non-normal is happening. You will have the same behavior if you write the code in a script tag in an HTML file and open with your browser

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: I don't think you understand what I am asking.  Never mind :)

Comment: You are asking why in global context var add the variable to a the global object but inside a function var does not add the variable to the global object. The answer is that is just how `var` is specified to work

Comment: I think the real answer to your confusion is that ** You will have the same behavior if you write the code in a script tag in an HTML file and open with your browser** -- basically `runInThisContext()` is its own context like a new browser window or an empty node.js file. I think you may be thinking that it executes the code you pass to it inside a function or something - it does not. It is an empty top-level context just like an empty browser window

Comment: I think you're right and I am over complicating this.  Do you know why `A` case doesn't fail ? since I am using `a` without a declaration ? If you open a file `index.js` and type `a=5`, it fails, but not in terms of `vm` as in my above code

Comment: Yes, without a `var` declaration it assumed to be global (not in strict mode. but otherwise yes). Really, please read up on [Scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)

Comment: Declaring a variable without the `var` keyword is javascript's method for declaring a global variable. If you don't like this "feature" you need to add the string `"use strict";` as the first line of code

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.